# Trigger ID from Table A to Table B

Tags: mysql, powershell, phpmyadmin

I have two Tables as follows:

Report
[image: reports]

Checks

[image: check]

ID column on Table "Report" has AI (Auto-Increment enabled and set to Primary Key)

ID column on Table "Checks" has AI (Auto-Increment Disabled and Indexed)

Here are my Foreign Key Constraints created under "checks" Table:

Foreign Key
[image]

What I need to accomplish is:

- Whenever I run my Powershell query to insert a new row into table "Report", I need the same ID to get written under the ID column of the "Checks" Table.

Powershell Query:

"INSERT INTO Checks (WiFi, Printers, Notepad) VALUES ('$WiFi', '$Printers', '$NotepadPlus')"

- Should I create a trigger in phpmyadmin in this case? and if so could anyone please assist with this?
- Do I need to specify the ID in my Powershell command above? if yes how could this be done?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can specify the ID in PowerShell command.

I assume you are using Powershell command to insert into `Reports` too. To capture new ID generated you can use `$command.LastInsertedId` and it can be used while inserting into `checks` table.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

SQL for creating TRIGGER to insert ID to Checks table:

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `dbname`.`trigger_name` AFTER INSERT ON `Report` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
insert into Checks (id) values (NEW.id)
END
```

But the values '$WiFi', '$Printers', '$NotepadPlus' cannot be inserted by TRIGGER. You need to set these values by Updating the row related to the new inserted ID in your PHP code.

Comment: I created the trigger: CREATE TRIGGER `trigger_report` AFTER INSERT ON `report`
 FOR EACH ROW insert into Checks (id) values (NEW.id) and added this to my powershell query: $ChecksID = $query1.LastInsertedId